# how to move one element from a list to another in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
def ListNum(x):
    list1 = []
    for i in (x):
        if x[i] < x [i + 1]:
            list1.append[i]
        else:
            break
    return(list1)
ListNum([1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4])
```

So, I input a list of numbers and go through the list and check if the first value in that list is less than the second value if so add it to `list1`, carry on until the value is greater than the next value.

So, if I input `ListNum([1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4])`

i should get `list1[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

but its not working

Comment: Should `ListNum([1,2,3,4])` return `[1,2,3,4]` or just `[1,2,3]` ?

Comment: What result are you getting? Is it an error message?

Comment: so if you enter ListNum([1,2,3,4]) it should return [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you *never* want to add the last item in `x` to `list1` because there isn't an item after it to compare it with.

Your code doesn't work properly because `for i in (x):` iterates over the *items* in `x`, not their indices. But even if it did iterate over the  indices your code could crash with an `IndexError` because it could attempt to compare the last item in the list with the item after it, which doesn't exist

Here are several ways to do this.

```
from itertools import takewhile

def list_nums0(x):
    list1 = []
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        if x[i] < x[i + 1]:
            list1.append(x[i])
        else:
            break
    return list1

def list_nums1(x):
    list1 = []
    for u, v in zip(x, x[1:]):
        if u < v:
            list1.append(u)
        else:
            break
    return list1

def list_nums2(x):
    list1 = []
    for i, u in enumerate(x[:-1], 1):
        if u < x[i]:
            list1.append(u)
        else:
            break
    return list1

def list_nums3(x):
    return [t[0] for t in takewhile((lambda a:a[0] < a[1]), zip(x, x[1:]))]

list_nums = list_nums3
print(list_nums([1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4]))
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`list_nums0` simply iterates over the indices of `x`.

`list_nums1` uses `zip` to iterate in parallel over `x` and `x[1:]`. This puts the current & next items into `u` and `v`.

`list_nums2` uses `enumerate` to get the current item in `u` and the index of the next item in `i`.

`list_nums3` uses `takewhile` to iterate over the tuples yielded by `zip` until we get a pair of items that don't satisfy the test. It performs the whole operation in a list comprehension, which is slightly more efficient that using `.append` in a traditional `for` loop.

---

Here are versions that also add the last item in the list if we get that far. The simple way to do this is to create a new temporary list that has a last item guaranteed to be greater than the "real" last item.

```
from itertools import takewhile

def list_nums0(x):
    x = x + [x[-1] + 1]
    list1 = []
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        if x[i] < x[i + 1]:
            list1.append(x[i])
        else:
            break
    return list1

def list_nums1(x):
    list1 = []
    for u, v in zip(x, x[1:] + [x[-1] + 1]):
        if u < v:
            list1.append(u)
        else:
            break
    return list1

def list_nums2(x):
    x = x + [x[-1] + 1]
    list1 = []
    for i, u in enumerate(x[:-1], 1):
        if u < x[i]:
            list1.append(u)
        else:
            break
    return list1

def list_nums3(x):
    return [t[0] for t in takewhile((lambda a:a[0] < a[1]), zip(x, x[1:] + [x[-1] + 1]))]

# test all the functions

funcs = (
    list_nums0,
    list_nums1,
    list_nums2,
    list_nums3,
)

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0]
print('data', data)
for i, list_nums in enumerate(funcs):
    print(i, list_nums(data))

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print('data', data)
for i, list_nums in enumerate(funcs):
    print(i, list_nums(data))
```

**output**

```
data [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0]
0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
2 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
3 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Of course, this strategy will fail if you pass an empty list. The simple way around that is to put this at the top of the function:

```
if not x:
    return []
```

Eg,

```
def list_nums1(x):
    if not x:
        return []
    list1 = []
    for u, v in zip(x, x[1:] + [x[-1] + 1]):
        if u < v:
            list1.append(u)
        else:
            break
    return list1
```

We can rewrite `list_nums3` like this to keep it a one-liner:

```
def list_nums3(x):
    return [] if not x else [t[0] for t in takewhile((lambda a:a[0] < a[1]), zip(x, x[1:] + [x[-1] + 1]))]
```

Comment: what about the 6? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: @adam In `[1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4]`, 6 is not less than the following item 2, so we don't copy it to the new list and we break out of the loop.

Comment: @adam: Ok I just saw your new comment on the question. Give me a couple of minutes...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the indexes, you can zip your list like this:

```
def ListNum(x):
    list1 = []
    for e1, e2 in zip(x, x[1:]):
        if e1 < e2:
            list1.append(e1)
        else:
            break
    return list1
```

This also has the benefit of fixing the bug when the list is sorted.

Comment: this works, but do you mind explain how the zip works. Never used it before. (also, thank you! I'm very grateful )

Comment: @adam: See [the docs for `zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip). Also see the related function [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

Answer (score 1):

If you do `for i in x`, you iterate through elements in `x`, not their indexes.

To iterate through indexes, you have to do `for i in range(len(x))`.

Comment: Why not `for index, value in enumerate(x)` ?

Comment: That's another option, although I'd do `for index, _ in enumerate(list1)` because `value` is not used.

Comment: @yper the value *is* use... it is appended to `list1`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OP meant to use `i` as index, not value. See the result he wants.

Comment: @yper The OP's code is all sorts of confused. `.append[i]` will throw an error anyway. I can only *assume* OP means to add the value due to this: "go through the list and check if the first value in that list is less than the second value if so add it to list1"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's true. He probably wants to do `list1.append(x[i])`.